# Difference between Subquery and Correlated Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, correlated-subquery

Is the following piece of SQL Query a normal query or a Correlated Subquery ??

```
SELECT UserID,
       FirstName,
       LastName,
       DOB,
       GFName,
       GLName,
       LoginName,
       LoginEffectiveDate,
       LoginExpiryDate,
       Password,
       Email,
       ReportingTo,
       Mobile,
       CommunicationPreference,
       IsActive
FROM   (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY FirstName) AS Row,
               UserID,
               FirstName,
               LastName,
               DOB,
               GFName,
               GLName,
               LoginName,
               LoginEffectiveDate,
               LoginExpiryDate,
               Password,
               Email,
               ReportingTo,
               Mobile,
               CommunicationPreference,
               IsActive
        FROM   DivakarUserRegistration)  T
```

Also, can someone state the difference between the both

Comment: This is actually a [derived table](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/112098-1.shtml). Btw, you failed to copy/paste closing parenthesis and an alias for derived table.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Correlated Subquery is a sub-query that uses values from the outer query. In this case the inner query has to be executed for every row of outer query.

See example here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

Simple subquery doesn't use values from the outer query and is being calculated only once:

```
SELECT id, first_name 
FROM student_details 
WHERE id IN (SELECT student_id
FROM student_subjects 
WHERE subject= 'Science');
```

**CoRelated  Subquery Example -**

Query To Find all employees whose salary is above average for their department

```
 SELECT employee_number, name
       FROM employees emp
       WHERE salary > (
         SELECT AVG(salary)
           FROM employees
           WHERE department = emp.department);
```

Comment: I heard from my collegues that it is a correlated subquery. But i am not able to understand how, since the inner query runs independently.

So, is my query a correlated subquery or a normal subquery ?

Comment: There is no correlated subquery there

Comment: I don't see a correlated subquery in the provided example.

Comment: It is a simple subquery that provided in example, correlated one you can find following the wiki-link. Please forgive my answer for being a bit messy

Comment: "*In this case the inner query has to be executed for every row of outer query*" - note that this is how it is _logically_ executed. Most modern optimizers will probably rewrite a co-related subquery into a join if possible (and thus avoiding the expensive row-by-row execution of the sub-query)

Comment: Plenty of modern poorly performing queries using correlated subqueries are improved by manually replacing the correlated subqueries. Plus, what happens if one's optimizer isn't one on that list?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name "Most modern optimizers will probably rewrite a co-related subquery into a join if possible " that's a pretty vague generalization, I wouldn't rely on the assumption that the optimizer will fix bad code. Correlated subqueries are RBAR, loops that run Row-By-Agonizing-Row, and should be avoided in user code. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/105972/  "the correlated subquery needs to be executed for every candidate row in the outer query".

Answer (score 86):

Above example is not Co-related Sub-Query. It is Derived Table / Inline-View since i.e, a Sub-query within FROM Clause.

A Corelated Sub-query should refer its parent(main Query) Table in it. For example See find the Nth max salary by Co-related Sub-query:

```
SELECT Salary 
FROM Employee E1
WHERE N-1 = (SELECT COUNT(*)
             FROM Employee E2
             WHERE E1.salary <E2.Salary)
```

**Co-Related Vs Nested-SubQueries.**

Technical difference between Normal Sub-query and Co-related sub-query are:

**1. Looping:**
    Co-related sub-query loop under main-query; whereas nested not; therefore co-related sub-query executes on each iteration of main query. Whereas in case of Nested-query; subquery executes first then outer query executes next. Hence, the maximum no. of executes are NXM for correlated subquery and N+M for subquery.

**2. Dependency(Inner to Outer vs Outer to Inner):**
    In the case of co-related subquery, inner query depends on outer query for processing whereas in normal sub-query, Outer query depends on inner query.

**3.Performance:**
    Using Co-related sub-query performance decreases, since, it performs NXM iterations instead of N+M iterations. ¨ Co-related Sub-query Execution.

For more information with examples :

http://dotnetauthorities.blogspot.in/2013/12/Microsoft-SQL-Server-Training-Online-Learning-Classes-Sql-Sub-Queries-Nested-Co-related.html

Comment: @nayeemDotNetAutorities "Above example is not Co-related Sub-Query" ? what is Above here? If it's relative to other answer Plz refrain from using such relative terms while answering wrt to another answer. Because what might be above now might get changed later.

Comment: above example = OP's query... usually, the answers refer to the question, sometimes to other answers, but referencing the one who owns that answer...

Comment: What;s NXM?>>>>

Answer (score 9):

A subquery is a select statement that is embedded in a clause of another select statement.

EX:

```
select ename, sal 
from emp  where sal > (select sal 
                       from emp where ename ='FORD');
```

A Correlated subquery is a subquery that is evaluated once for each row processed by the outer query or main query. Execute the Inner query based on the value fetched by the Outer query all the values returned by the main query are matched. The INNER Query is driven by the OUTER Query.

Ex:

```
select empno,sal,deptid 
from emp e 
where sal=(select avg(sal) 
           from emp where deptid=e.deptid);
```

DIFFERENCE

The inner query executes first and finds a value, the outer query executes once using the value from the inner query (subquery)

Fetch by the outer query, execute the inner query using the value of the outer query, use the values resulting from the inner query to qualify or disqualify the outer query (correlated)

**For more information :**
http://www.oraclegeneration.com/2014/01/sql-interview-questions.html

Answer (score 8):

CORRELATED SUBQUERIES:   Is evaluated for each row processed by the Main query. Execute the Inner query based on the value fetched by the Outer query. Continues till all the values returned by the main query are matched. The INNER Query is driven by the OUTER Query

Ex:

`SELECT empno,fname,sal,deptid FROM emp e WHERE sal=(SELECT AVG(sal) FROM emp WHERE deptid=e.deptid)`

The Correlated subquery specifically computes the `AVG(sal)` for each department.

SUBQUERY:      Runs first,executed once,returns values to be used by the MAIN Query. The OUTER  Query is driven by the INNER QUERY

Answer (score 2):

I think below explanation will help to you..
 differentiation between those:
`Correlated subquery` is an inner query referenced by main query (outer query) such that inner query considered as being excuted repeatedly.

`non-correlated subquery` is a sub query that is an independent of the outer query and it can executed on it's own without relying on main outer query.

`plain subquery` is not dependent on the outer query,

Comment: I heard from my collegues that it is a correlated subquery. But i am not able to understand how, since the inner query runs independently.

So, is my query a correlated subquery or a normal subquery ?

Answer (score 2):

when it comes to subquery and co-related query both have inner query and outer query the only difference is in subquery the inner query doesn't depend on outer query, whereas in co-related inner query depends on outer.

Answer (score 0):

In an SQL query, if the inner query executes for every row of the outer query. If the inner query is executed for once and the result is consumed by the outer query, then it is called as non co-related query.

[Correlated sub-queries usually correspond to normal join queries, i.e. join queries that have no sub-queries, and can usually be expressed as such. It is sometimes recommended that they are translated into such join queries, because most SQL DBMSs will execute them .....](http://www.exploredatabase.com/2018/02/what-is-correlated-subquery-in-sql-oracle.html)

Answer (score 0):

As a SQL student, what helped me understand the difference in a `subquery` and a `correlated subquery` is that there is usually a reference to both queries in the `WHERE` clause.

For example, when looking at all the other solutions on this post you might notice a trend:

1. `where deptid=e.deptid` notice the `e.` which is the main query
2. `WHERE department = emp.department` notice the `emp.` which is the main query
3. `WHERE E1.salary <E2.Salary` this one labels both `E1.` as the main query and `E2.` as the correlated subquery.

I do not see a reference to both the main query *and* the subquery in the `WHERE` clause of the question, so no, *I would say this is not a correlated subquery*.

Thank you to everyone in this post!