# SQL Query Performance Issue sub-query and missing parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlperformance

I have two Questions in the below query

1. When i tried running the query I am getting the below error in oracle
2. Performance issue i.e when i run the query without the IN clause i.e remove the {select * from cand_profile where postal_code in } in the below query it is taking 15 sec .How to fine tune this sql query ?

Query

```
select *
from cand_profile 
where postal_code in (
    SELECT ZIP
    FROM (
        SELECT
            dest.ID,
            dest.postal_code AS ZIP,
            ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(src.latitude))*SIN(RADIANS(dest.latitude))+COS(RADIANS(src.latitude))*COS(RADIANS(dest.latitude))*COS(RADIANS(src.longitude)-RADIANS(dest.longitude)))* 3959 AS DISTANCE
        FROM post_codes dest
            CROSS JOIN
        post_codes src
        WHERE src.ID = (
            SELECT ID
            FROM post_codes
            WHERE postal_code = '60195'
            GROUP BY ID
        ) 
        AND ( dest.ID <> src.ID OR  dest.ID = src.ID )
    )
    GROUP BY ID,ZIP,DISTANCE
    HAVING DISTANCE <= 5
    ORDER BY DISTANCE
))
```

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: What you show in your question includes 16 left parentheses and 17 right parentheses.  You have an extra right parenthesis at the end.

Comment: For understanding about Correlated Subquery's poor performace, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268848/difference-between-subquery-and-correlated-subquery?answertab=votes#tab-top . To say, the inner query will be executed every time for every row in the outer query.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?: AND ( dest.ID <> src.ID OR  dest.ID = src.ID )

Comment: `( dest.ID <> src.ID OR  dest.ID = src.ID )` ???

Comment: @GordonLinoff ha.  I just might favorite this question because of that. senthil , if you are trying to include everything, you could either omit that line (because everything is already included by default), or do "(1=1)".  Or do a "not null" if you are trying to filter nulls or something...

Comment: `dest.ID <> src.ID OR dest.ID = src.ID` is not equivalent to `1=1`; it's equivalent to `dest.ID IS NOT NULL AND src.ID IS NOT NULL` because of the way `NULL` comparisons work in Oracle. `NULL = NULL` and `NULL <> NULL` are always `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'in' clause tends to be very inefficient.  I would try to use a join instead:

```
select c.*
from cand_profile c
join (
    SELECT ZIP
    FROM (
        SELECT dest.ID,dest.postal_code AS ZIP, ACOS(SIN ( RADIANS( src.latitude) ) * SIN ( RADIANS ( dest.latitude )) 
+ COS ( RADIANS ( src.latitude)) * COS ( RADIANS ( dest.latitude )) * COS ( RADIANS( src.longitude ) - RADIANS ( dest.longitude ))) * 3959
AS DISTANCE
        FROM post_codes dest
            CROSS JOIN
        post_codes src
        WHERE src.ID = (
            SELECT ID
            FROM post_codes
            WHERE postal_code = '60195'
            GROUP BY ID
        ) 
        AND ( dest.ID <> src.ID OR  dest.ID = src.ID )
    )
    GROUP BY ID,ZIP,DISTANCE
    HAVING DISTANCE <= 5
    ORDER BY DISTANCE
) a
on postal_code = a.ZIP
```

Comment: @Senthil the problem might be that your original query had 1 extra parenthesis in it.. try the query now.  About the (1=1), this should produce exactly the same results as the line originally had, but I am not sure what you were trying to accomplish with that line because all ID's should either = or <>.. thus it is inclusive of everything.

Comment: - john ,I tried the above query which took in 15.16 sec . Also tried using (1=1) which also give me 15 sec ..

Comment: @Senthil 15 seconds is not terribly slow..  But it's hard to find out exactly what is taking the most time, without seeing an execution plan (my guess would be the "distance" calculation though; there is a lot of processing going on there)

Comment: ORA-01428: argument '1.00000000000000000000000000000000000001' is out of range
01428. 00000 -  "argument '%s' is out of range"
*Cause:    
*Action: