# Aggrgating Group Query (list newest Entry out of Group of same id )

Tags: mysql, sql

Version:mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux

Table articles:

```
id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `creator` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `versionid` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `content` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `publishdate` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

When an article is updated he gets a **new id**, but **versionid is the same**.
I can't find a query to Select all articles, but only the **newest of those**, which have the **same versionid**.

Answer (score 1):

use correlated subquery

```
    select t1.* from table_name t1
    where t1.id= ( select max(id) 
                    from table_name t2 where t1.versionid=t2.versionid
                 )
```

Comment: You are my hero! :)

Comment: Correlated subquery is slow like hell. It runs N+1 queries, one query for each row.

Comment: @gaborsch have you checked the query plan of your query and my query :)

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Yes, I did. Yours is using a DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, my query is using a derived table.

Comment: If you have a question, which one is better, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268848/difference-between-subquery-and-correlated-subquery/21036822#21036822