# INSERT INTO based on SELECT and versioned record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains the current state of employees like below :

```
 SELECT EmployeeId ,OfficeId from EmpCurrent
```

The output is like below :

```
EmployeeId OfficeId
54          67
64          57
89          23
```

And I have another table containing the full history for an employee except for OfficeId which isn't historised (I added the column OfficeId which is NULL to insert from EmpCurrent) :

```
SELECT EmployeeId ,Func AS [Function],OfficeId,Version from EmpHistory
```

The output is like below for EmployeeId=54:

```
EmployeeId Function OfficeId Version
54         Manager  NULL     1
54         Director NULL     2
54         HeadOf   NULL     3
```

I want to get the OfficeId from EmpCurrent and insert it in EmpHistory in the last Version(max version) of the each Employee, my output will be like below :

```
EmployeeId Function OfficeId Version
54         Manager  NULL     1
54         Director NULL     2
54         HeadOf   67       3
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you getting stuck with it? This is a pretty standard use case for either a [correlated subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17269406/1324345) or a windowing function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8b5247db0abdcaaec5e96960eb4518ae)

**Firstly,** You need to get 3 fields `h.EmployeeId, c.OfficeId, max(Version) as MaxVersion`.

**Secondly,** Update `h.OfficeId = cte.OfficeId` on `#EmpHistory` table with 2 conditions `h.EmployeeId = cte.EmployeeId and MaxVersion = h.Version`

**Full Code**

```
;with cte as( 
select h.EmployeeId, c.OfficeId, max(Version) as MaxVersion
from #EmpHistory h
inner join #EmpCurrent c on h.EmployeeId = c.EmployeeId
group by h.EmployeeId, c.OfficeId
)

update h
set h.OfficeId = cte.OfficeId
from #EmpHistory h
inner join cte on h.EmployeeId = cte.EmployeeId and MaxVersion = h.Version
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want the most recent value for the `join`, then:

```
select eh.*, ec.officeid
from (select eh.*,
             row_number() over (partition by employeeid order by version desc) as seqnum
      from emphistory eh
     ) eh left join
     empcurrent ec
     on ec.employeeid = eh.employeeid and eh.seqnum = 1;
```

This is one of the unusual instances where you filter on the *first* table  in a `left join`.  You can also do this as:

```
select eh.*,
       (case when eh.seqnum = 1 then ec.officeid end) as officeid
from (select eh.*,
             row_number() over (partition by employeeid order by version desc) as seqnum
      from emphistory eh
     ) eh left join
     empcurrent ec
     on ec.employeeid = eh.employeeid ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH CTE_EMP
AS
(
    SELECT 
        EH.EmployeeId
        ,Version        = MAX(Version)
    FROM
        EmpHistory AS EH
    GROUP BY
        EH.EmployeeId
)
select 
     EH.EmployeeId
    ,EH.Func
    ,OfficeId       = CASE WHEN CTE.Version = EH.Version THEN EC.OfficeId END
    ,EH.Version
from 
    EmpHistory AS EH 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EmpCurrent AS EC ON EC.EmployeeId = EH.EmployeeId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_EMP AS CTE ON CTE.EmployeeId = EH.EmployeeId
```